# Data Migration Text Type on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, grails-2.0

I'm trying to use the [database-migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) for Grails, but I'm running into a funky problem with property types of `text`.

Generating a baseline log is setting the type as `text(255)`, but this is an error because there is no precision. The same happens when I try to modify datatype to `text`.

```
changeSet(author: "jgiotta (generated)", id: "1348767652354-2") {
    modifyDataType(columnName: "old_value", newDataType: "text",
        schemaName: "dbo", tableName: "audit_trail")
}
```

What can I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: Why are you moving to `text` and not `varchar(max)`?

Comment: It was `varchar(max)` before I introduced the database-migration plugin, but `varchar(255)` since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a little bit of additional mapping.

Originally I was only doing:

```
static mapping = {
    oldValue type: 'text'
    //...
}
```

What forced the type to at least `nvarchar(max)` was the following mapping:

```
static mapping = {
    oldValue type: 'text', sqlType: 'text'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the character set setting on the connection driver (ODBC/JDBC).
I had similar issue when bringing NVARCHAR field over using a replication tool. Nulls were being written to target because the ODBC driver didn't understand NVARCHAR with ASCII character map.
In short, issue was that the replication tool was using ODBC driver with ASCII character set.  Once, I changed the ODBC driver to use UTF8 character set, I started seeing NVARCHAR data on target.